# PHP Carbon add dynamic object property inside double quoted string

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I am trying to build a Carbon date from an existing Laravel date that uses dynamic object properties:

```
private static function createEvent($booking, $service) {
    dd(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', "$booking->service_{$service}_date_end $booking->service_1_time_end"));
}
```

This keeps returning:

> Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found.
>   Data missing

Any idea how I can get this to work? I can't seem to pass the variables directly to Carbon as it expects a string as a second parameter. The double quotes make things a little tricky.

Comment: you could try proper interpolation of the variable... `$booking->{"service_$service_date_end"}.' '.$booking->service_1_time_end`

Comment: dd("$booking->service_{$service}_date_end$booking->service_1_time_end") and post result

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_date_end' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: @DaveCarruthers That also returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_date_end' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: To hard to do on one line, IMO.  Not worth the readability issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break this down a bit you have 2 properties one is dynamic.

So to access a dynamic property you can do this

```
 $prop = "service_{$service}_date_end";

 $booking->{$prop}
```

Then we just have a standard property an a space, so then putting that togather

```
     dd(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $booking->{$prop}.' '.$booking->service_1_time_end"));
```

Now you may be able to put them together on one line, but you are basically double interpolating variables.  So it's easier to read and do if you take care of the one then do the other.

For me readability is everything, keep it simple and it will work.

That said I think this approach is fundamentally flawed, as you have no real way to know if the property actually exists.  So you are leaving yourself open to errors like, undefined object property .

You could do it more robustly using a simple switch statement.

But, without knowing the full scope of how you are using it or where `$service` comes from I can't say that, it may be fine in your use case.  I just wanted to give you a word of caution.

Comment: Yeah I was going to ask if its possible to include it all on one line.. but probably a better idea not to. This works great thanks.

Comment: Yea, but it's prone to breaking.  For me it's not Robust enough to use in production level code.  That is just my opinion, and you may have a valid use case where it makes sense.  However I have no way to know that ... lol

Comment: Are you referring to the one-liner approach or this whole approach in general?

Comment: PS I actually changed my comment, before you responded so I don't know which one you used.  The first time I realized it wouldn't work.

Comment: No, just that fact that the class property may not exist, and there are no checks on it.  So if `$service`  was equal to `foo` it would give you a fatal error and you have no way to check for that currently.  But as I said without knowing the full scope of how you are using it I can't really tell you not too.  Some use cases this may be fine in, if there are restrictions on what the variable can be. IE it may never be wrong because of those other "checks"  Such as a foreach loop on a hard coded array etc...

Comment: Yeah I understand. I am checking the $service variable and doing all my error handling before it reaches that point.